# Putting home directory under source control (hg)

Tags: mercurial, home-directory

For a while I had just my code under source control, but I decided it would be cool to put things like my stuff in my .vim folder among other things in a repo. (I'm obviously not going to store everything in my repo, just various config files, my src directory, and maybe a few other things as well)

I was able to set up a repo fine, then push it to my server where I can access it from my other computers, but I can't clone it to my other computers. When I try to clone it it fails because the home directory isn't empty. Is there a way to do what I want here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the versioned files between my computers are the same, what I did was:

```
~$ hg clone ssh://myserver/hg/dotfiles mydotfiles
~$ mv mydotfiles/.hg .
~$ rm -rf mydotfiles
```

and that's it, now your home folder is under version control, but of course if your dot files are not identical between computers you will have to do something about it.

Since I only want to version some files and not everything under my home folder, I have this simple rule in `~/.hgignore`

```
# This .hgignore is for the dotfiles repository only,
# the rest of my HG repositories use the file
# .hgignore_global as referenced by [ui]'s ignore setting.

syntax:glob
*
```

This way I don't get an ocean of files when I do `hg status` and only see those files that I have under version control that have been modified.

But since I want to see unversioned files when working within another hg repository, I have this in my `~/.hgrc` file

```
[ui]
ignore=/home/gajon/.hgignore_global
```

And `~/.hgignore_global` contains some filters for common transient files:

```
syntax: glob
*.pyc
*~
.*.swp
.svn*
*.svn*
*.fasl

syntax: regexp
^\.pc/
```

Comment: another option was to 'hg init' and 'hg pull' rather than clone.

Comment: Ry4an, you are correct. And that could be more appropriate; no need to create a folder filled with files and then `rm -rf`ing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have *proj1* and *proj2*. *proj1* is a mercurial repo you want to clone to *proj2*, but *proj2* already has files in it.

Try this:

```
hg clone proj1 proj3
mv proj3/.hg proj2
rmdir proj3
cd proj2
hg update -C -r tip
```

Comment: You can omit the `-r tip` option of the last command - update takes the *tip* revision as default.

Answer (score 0):

In the other directories that already exist, you could `hg init`, `hg add` what you want, `hg commit` that, `hg pull` from the central repo, and deal with the resulting merge.

Comment: Have you tried this? It will only work if you force the pull. Personally, I think the 'copy the .hg directory' is a 'cleaner' answer